# How to add a function within a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    //function goes here
  });
});
```

The reason for this is so I can use the value of 'select' tag inside the functions I'm about to make.

Comment: Yes you can add a function inside your change function, something like `functionName($(this).val())` - this would run the function `functionName` with the value of a the selected value

Comment: Is it simply like `function foo()` and then I can use `this.value` to get the value of select?

Comment: Okay, thanks Carsten! I'll try it out

Comment: Yes, you can create nested function. But in your case, you can not call the nested function from outside the container function.

Comment: It's not clear: do you want to call a function from inside there or do you want to define a function there? If it's the latter, why? To return it? To pass it to another function?

Comment: I want to create a function inside there so I can use the value of select with `this`... or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Yes you are

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: `$("select").on("change", function() {
    console.log(this.value,$(this).val());
  });` works inside the handler - console.log is another function. You can replace it with your function using either this.value or $(this).val()

Comment: I highly suggest you learn how jquery works: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the function with the parameter like below.

`Yourfunction($(this).val())`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    Yourfunction($(this).val())
  });
});

function Yourfunction(value){
  console.log("The value from the select " + value)
}
```

Comment: Oh okay! This is how it's done. I'll try it!

Comment: It worked! Thank you! :)

Comment: @JanArielSanJose No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Call function and pass the jQuery "select" object as below.
In this way, you can retrieve all properties of "select" object in myFunc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    myFunc(this);
  });

  function myFunc(selector){
    console.log($(selector).val());
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense,  what is the point of running your function if the function is within the change?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry beginner mistake

Comment: @GGO I put `function myFunc()` inside "change" event listener